# Build looks different in machines that have same win10 os and 64 bit processor

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

Building electron package in two machines that has win10 os and 64 bit processor, gives two different build. I ran electron app in windows server 2012 and my local machine. I see built packages are of different size.

Local Machine Pic [image: Local Machine]
Server machine pic[image: ServerMAchine]

It behaves as expected in my local machine but it doesn’t behave as expected in windows server 2019 though it has same os and 64 bit processors

For Example node modules after npm install is 290mb in my local machine whereas in server it is 284mb.

This is how I run package
“electron-packager --out winx64 --overwrite --platform win32 --appname clientcenter . --icon=./logoA.ico --executable-name ClientCenter --no-prune --asar”